# Groovy HTTPBuilder SOAP response not being parsed properly

Tags: soap, groovy, httpbuilder

I don't understand why XmlSlurper is apparently not working on the result.

```
import groovyx.net.http.*
import static groovyx.net.http.ContentType.*
import static groovyx.net.http.Method.*


def String WSDL_URL = ...
def http = new HTTPBuilder( WSDL_URL , ContentType.XML )
String soapEnvelope = 
          """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
                         xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
                         xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
          <soap12:Body>
            <GetTerritories xmlns="...">
              <State>AZ</State>
              <ZipCode>85203</ZipCode>
            </GetTerritories>
          </soap12:Body>
        </soap12:Envelope>"""
        http.request( POST, XML ) {
             headers."Content-Type" = "application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8"
             headers."Accept" = "application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8"
             body = soapEnvelope

            response.success = { resp, xml ->     
                println "XML was ${xml}"
                println "Territories were ${xml.Territories}"
                println "State were ${xml.Territories.State}"
                println "City was ${xml.Territories.Territory.City}"
                println "County was ${xml.Territories.Territory.County}"
            }

            response.failure = { resp, xml ->
                xml
            }
        }
```

leads to

```
XML was <Territories><State>AZ</State><ZipCode>85203</ZipCode><Territory><City>Mesa</City><County>Maricopa</County>...</Territory></Territories>
Territories were 
State were 
City was 
County was
```

UPDATE: Thanks to John Wagenleitner's insight, I did a little more digging.

When I add that assert, I see an issue:

```
assert "Territories" == xml.name()
                     |  |   |
                     |  |   Envelope
                     |  <Territories><State>AZ</State><ZipCode>85203</ZipCode</Territories>
                     false
```

Changing the request parameters from `POST, XML` to `POST, TEXT` is revealing:

```
XML was <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope 
      xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" 
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
      xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <soap:Body>
        <GetTerritoriesResponse xmlns="...">
            <GetTerritoriesResult>&lt;Territories&gt;&lt;State&gt;AZ&lt;/State&gt;&lt;ZipCode&gt;85203&lt;/ZipCode&gt;&lt;Territory&gt;&lt;City&gt;Mesa&lt;/City&gt;&lt;County&gt;Maricopa&lt;/County&gt;...&lt;/Territory&gt;&lt;/Territories&gt;
            </GetTerritoriesResult>
        </GetTerritoriesResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

...

So it looks like the XmlSlurper, when the variable is being printed out, is throwing away the SOAP stuff and evaluating the innermost node () while not actually navigating to that node. Is this expected behavior?

I have been unable to find a a more complete and modern SOAP call and parse using httpBuilder, so I assumed XML would be the right content type. But it looks like I'll just have to accept TEXT and parse the body myself, which seems lame. Is there a better way of handling SOAP responses with httpBuilder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend printing the raw text of the response:

```
println "XML was ${resp.data.text}"
```

Assuming that the printed XML line is what you expect (though odd since there is no Envelope or Body nodes), then you should be able to remove **Territories** from your references to xml.  When parsed with XmlSlurper the root node is the GPathResult.

```
assert "Territories" == xml.name()
println "State were ${xml.State.text()}"
println "City were ${xml.Territory.City.text()}"
println "County were ${xml.Territory.County.text()}"
```

Also, just wanted to point out that the SOAP 1.2 media type is "application/soap+xml".

**UPDATE:**

> So it looks like the XmlSlurper, when the variable is being printed
>   out, is throwing away the SOAP stuff and evaluating the innermost node
>   () while not actually navigating to that node. Is this expected
>   behavior?

Yes, the toString() method for a GPathResult just prints all text nodes and not the actual elements or attributes.  With HTTPBuilder you can print out the raw response text by using:

```
println resp.data.text
```

> I have been unable to find a a more complete and modern SOAP call and
>   parse using httpBuilder, so I assumed XML would be the right content
>   type. But it looks like I'll just have to accept TEXT and parse the
>   body myself, which seems lame. Is there a better way of handling SOAP
>   responses with httpBuilder?

The ***ContentType.XML*** is fine, the issue is with how the SOAP response that your web service returns is formed.  The web service is sending back the ***Territories*** results as an encoded string in the ***GetTerritoriesResult*** element and not as part of the actual XML response that HTTPBuilder automatically parses for you (this is not a problem with the way HTTPBuilder is handling it).  Because the data you really want is in that encoded string you will need to parse the text node of the ***GetTerritoriesResult*** yourself.

```
response.success = { resp, xml ->     
    println "XML was ${resp.data.text}"
    def territories = new XmlSlurper().parseText(
        xml.Body.GetTerritoriesResponse.GetTerritoriesResult.text()
    )
    println "State were ${territories.State}"
    println "City was ${territories.Territory.City}"
    println "County was ${territories.Territory.County}"
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this comment was pretty helpful. From what I've read of Scott Davis' Groovy Recipes, I thought text() was for XmlParser, not XmlSlurper. I'm stymied by the mismatch between the print out of ${xml} and ${xml.name()}, though. Do you know why it's doing that?

Comment: When printing out the xml GPathResult it doesn't show the tags, just the text content, so that's why you are seeing the result you saw.

Comment: If you call text() on a GPathResult it will return a String with the text contents of that element.  When doing things like println it's usually not strictly necessary since the toString() method on a GPathResult also prints out the text contents of the element.